# Processing sql database lines one by one - select while also adding element

Tags: mysql

I want to build a script (c#) that will take fields elements from a SQL table and process them one by one. I would like to be able to run this script multiple times simultaneously so every instance of the script will take its own line of elements without interfering with the others.

What I had in mind is to have 3 fields Id, linkList and processed. The linkList will hold the links elements and the *processed* will hold 0 if the field was not processed yet, and 1 if it was processed. Every instance of the script will take the next available link that holds the *processed* field = 0 using this kind of query:

```
select * from links where processed = 0 limit 1
```

After taking the linkList element I want to update the processed field with the value of 1 so the next instance of the script knows that it's already processed and move to the next one. I can do that by running this query:

```
UPDATE links SET processed = 1 WHERE processed = 0 limit 1;
```

The issue is that if another instance of the script will access the database between the 2 SQL queries, it will find the *processed* value = 0 and will take the same linkList value twice.

What would be the best approach in solving this issue?

Comment: "The issues is that if another instance of the script will access the database between the 2 sql queries, it will find the processed value = 0 and will take the same linkList value twice." Why would you want to have multiple idential scripts doing processing of this kind? Sounds like a recipe for exactly that kind of confusion. Stick to one instance, unless you have an absolutely huge workload to process.

Comment: This is exactly the case, I have huge workload to process. This this the exact reason why I'm using SQL instead of a simple .txt file

Comment: In details U can use transactions etc, but idea of algorithm seems killing performance (heavy work of indexes, locking, flushing - BTW I guess U use indexes). Impossible to teach high performance database in comment

Comment: @CatherineAnderson how huge, exactly? Millions of rows to process every minute? Going from .txt to SQL would be necessary after you have a few hundred records in your file overall, no matter how fast you needed to process them. It would not on its own be a justification for needing multiple instances of your script. I see you found a solution, but unless your throughput is millions of records every few minutes, or each one takes more than a few seconds to process, you're unlikely really to need multiple simultaneous scripts running, using modern servers.

Comment: My SQL database has 60k rows of links and every instance of the script takes ~ 1 to 15 mins to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that using `for update` is exactly what I'm searching for:

```
select * from links where processed = 0 limit 1 for update;
UPDATE links SET processed = 1 WHERE processed = 0 limit 1;
```